# Delete firestore document based on rule

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I created an app where people can upload some images of some themselves.

Now, In order to deal with cases where people can upload inappropriate images, I created a reporting system. What I'm doing is basically every time someone reports the image, the ID of the reporting person is added to an array in `firestore` like this:

```
db
    .collection( "Reports" )
    .document( ImageID )
    .update( "Reports", FieldValue.arrayUnion( UID ) );
```

Now, I want to set a rule that if for example, the size of the array is 5 (5 different people reports the image) that it will automatically delete that image from the cloud.

Is there any way I can do it instead of every time reading the array and check ist size?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common way to do that would be through Cloud Functions, which are server-side code that is automatically triggered when (for this use-case) something is written to Firestore. See the documentation on [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) and the page on [Firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events).

---

An alternate (but more involved) would be to secure access through a query and security rules. In this scenario you'd:

1. Add a `reportCount` to the document, and ensure this gets updated in sync with the reports.
2. From the application code use a query to only request images with a `reportCount` less than 5.
3. [Use security rules to only allow queries with that clause in it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query).

As said, this is more involved in the amount of code you write, but the advantage is that no server-side code is involved, and that documents are immediately blocked when too many reports come in for them.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a trigger on your `Reports` collection.

```js
export const updateReportTrigger = functions.firestore
  .document('Reports/{ImageID}')
  .onUpdate(onUpdate)

async function onUpdate({ before, after }, context) {
  const newData = after.data()
  if (newData && newData.Reports && newData.Reports.length > 5) {
    // put your delete logic here
    // you can access the document id through context.params.ImageID
  }
}
```

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events